# Why do I get this error value success of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to JSONOBJECT?

Tags: php, android, json

I am developing this android app which I send the data on server and then I have to retrieve the data and show them on a chart (anychartLibrary).

I've written this php code which helps me send the date to the server and retrieve the data related to that date, but instead of getting a jsonObject I get this html line, which I have noticed using Postman...

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {

    require_once('init.php');

    $myDate =$_GET['myDate'];

    $sql =" SELECT * FROM parkinsonism_value WHERE myDate='$myDate' ;";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if (isset($row)) {       
        $record['myDate'] = $row['myDate'];
        $record['parkinsonism'] = $row['parkinsonism'];            
    } else {
        $record['myDate'] ="";
        $record['parkinsonism'] ="";
    }

    header('Content-type=application/json');
    echo json_encode(array("list"=>$record),JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);      
}
?>
```

and this is the volley json Object Request:

```
public void getString(){
    String url = "http://46.4.151.237/StHans/getparkinsonism.php"+"?myDate="+finalDate;

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        Toast.makeText(getContext(),response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                 jsObject =response.getJSONObject("list");
                 sss =jsObject.getString("parkinsonism");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
    MySingleton.getInstance(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

by the way about the final date:

```
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
dayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

finalDate =dayOfMonth +"/"+(month +1)+"/"+ year;
```

now I have this error which tells me value success of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to JSONOBJECT.
what should I change to get this to work?
thanks:|

Comment: `header('Content-Type: application/json')`.

Comment: @Jonnix : thanks, Now I have the json :) but I still get the error

Comment: What does the response look like?

Comment: @showdev what do you mean?

Comment: What does your PHP output?

Comment: Have you tried making the whole request for json array ? since the response from php is in an array

Comment: @showdev it returns a json like :
{
    "list": {
        "myDate": "2/8/2019",
        "parkinsonism": "10"
    }
}

Comment: @BryanLoresto sorry, not familiar with php , how can I do so?

Comment: @seyedaliAghamali  { "list": { "myDate": "2/8/2019", "parkinsonism": "10" } }  is the actual response, Its a valid json object so it might be a different problem

Comment: @BryanLoresto ok! I used trim() after getString() now I get some different response inside my app which is like this :
{"list":{"myDate": "2\/8\/2019", "parkinsonism": "10" } }  so why do i get these extra backslashes since I'm using the unescaped slashes in php?

Comment: @BryanLoresto , u get backslashes because json object has been converted to string.

Comment: @seyedaliAghamali  you can get object in new json object by first get the response in string. JsonObject you are creating and response JsonObject are not of same type. kindly check there parent classes. this may be a problem.